# Is there a Media player that can skip the silent parts of an audio/video?

Tags: media-player

Is there a Media player that can skip the silent parts of an audio/video?

While watching lectures, it is annoying to be stuck in the real time and going at the same rate of the actual thing, where one can just simply jump into the juicy bits! The pauses in lectures are a complete time waste!

Comment: Interesting. Issue is what do you define as silent? Recorded lectures often are very quiet during pauses, but not 100% _silent_. As Woolnut already said, your best bet is a nice media player that allows you to see the waveform.

Comment: @Insane assume anything below a certain volume threshold is silence. Of course we can change this value

Comment: This is the [best you'll get](http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Truncate_Silence). Pretty easy in Audacity.

Answer (score 3):

Use Chrome with the open source extension [Skip Silence](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/skip-silence/fhdmkhbefcbhakffdihhceaklaigdllh?hl=en).

Note that additional steps may be necessary if you are trying to play a local file.

[Here](https://github.com/vantezzen/skip-silence) is the GitHub repository for this extension.

Tip: If you don't like to install too many extensions that may affect your browser's performance, you can always create a new profile/user which will allow a separate profile of extensions to be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the closest you will get is to use a Media player that shows the waveform of the track you are playing. If this is something you would consider it would be worth looking at [**foobar2000**](http://www.foobar2000.org/) as it shows the waveform of the file allowing you to see where the "silent" parts are!

You will need to install the [**Waveform Seekbar**](https://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_wave_seekbar) component **in addition to the main foobar2000 software** to achieve this, the software is incredibly lightweight and i have used before for a similar situation a few years back!

Answer (score 1):

[Music Bee](https://getmusicbee.com/) has that feature, it's a great music player, only for Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i found so far is to upload the video on youtube and watch it with an android app called [NewPipe](https://newpipe.schabi.org/) with the "skip silence" option turned on.

Answer (score 0):

## By [heartlog](https://github.com/heartlog)

[Player](https://github.com/moneytoo/Player)

This player support skip silence feature..
Go to **in app settings** and enable it there..
Hope it helps..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).